# How would I refactor repetitive code?

Tags: java, loops, refactoring

Apologies for the poor title, but I can't really think of an informative title for this.

I'll be straight forward here:

```
setName(); // set the name field
validate(); // submit the form and check if form has error

setName();
setAge();
validate();

setName();
setAge();
setHeight();
validate();

setName();
setAge();
setHeight();
setGender();
validate();

// the list goes on...
```

I am testing a form on a website and the form should not allow any empty fields, however upon a submit button click any fields that I've entered in before gets **cleared**, which is why I need to set the previous fields all over again like the above code.

What would be a more elegant way to write this? I was thinking of a loop but then I could not think of the right conditions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Runnable` instance for each of the actions and put them in a list.

- In Java 8+:

  ```
  List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<>();
  runnables.add(() -> setName());
  runnables.add(() -> setAge());
  runnables.add(() -> setHeight());
  // ... etc
  ```
- For earlier versions of Java, you can use anonymous classes:

  ```
  runnables.add(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { setName(); } });
  // ... etc
  ```

and then execute the `Runnable` instances in a sublist of `runnables`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < runnables.size(); ++i) {
  for (Runnable fn : runnables.subList(0, i + 1)) {
    fn.run();
  }
  validate();
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/niuXob)

Comment: Hey Andy, this looks very interesting (something I've never seen before!). However I am getting `Syntax error on tokens, Expression expected instead` error where the `runnables.add(() ->` is. Is this something related to the version of JDK im using? which is **J2SE-1.5**

Comment: You are using Java *5*? You do know that not only is Java 5 past end of life, but so are Javas 6 and 7, right? Upgrade - it's not 2004 any more! You'd need Java 8 to use this syntax. Edited to add pre-Java 8 syntax.

Comment: I know Andy, I know. And it pains me because this is a legacy project that I cannot just simply upgrade java version (it'll break a lot of things and we wouldn't want to risk it). Anyways thanks for the other suggestion, I'll definitely check it out when I get home. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as to whether I fully understand your question (perhaps a pastebin as to a working example would help), however perhaps you could have a boolean for each field that checks as to whether the field has been modified since the last check, and then you set field based on the state of these booleans?

The checking method would then reset all booleans to false (or whatever method actually submits the changes).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the attribute of the fields....but thank you for your suggestion!